# Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Суть в том, что мне необходимо сначала проверять входящие данные с тем, что уже есть в таблице. если совпадений не найдено - добавлять данные (как новые) на следующие строки.

Пробую таким образом.

```
function onEdit(event)
{
  var content = JSON.parse(event.postData.contents);
  var ss = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if(r.getColumn() == 2){ //column B
    if(r.getValue() == content['order'].order_number) {

     var id = ss.getRange('B'+r.getRow()).getValue();  // order id from the column A

ss.getRange('V'+r.getRow()).setValue(content['order'].status+' Время обновления статуса '+new Date());
    }
    else{
    row.push(new Date());
    row.push(content['order'].order_number)
    row.push(content['order'].shipping_address.first_name+' '+content['order'].shipping_address.last_name)
    row.push(content['order'].billing_address.email)

    row.push(content['order'].total_line_items_quantity);

    var item = "";
     for (var i=0;content['order'].line_items.length>i;i++){
       item=item+content['order'].line_items[i].quantity+' -'+content['order'].line_items[i].name+',';

    }

    item=item.substring(0,item.length-1);
    row.push(item);
    row.push(content['order'].total)
    row.push(content['order'].payment_details.paid)
    row.push(content['order'].status)
    row.push(content['order'].payment_details.method_title)
    row.push(content['order'].shipping_address.address_1+','+content['order'].shipping_address.city+','+content['order'].shipping_address.country+','+content['order'].billing_address.phone+', ZIP:'+content['order'].billing_address.postcode)

    row.push(content['order'].shipping_methods)

    row.push(content['order'].note)
    row.push(content['order'].view_order_url)

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheet id')
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    sheet.appendRow(row);
    result.result = 'ok';
    }


}
}
```

Если просто добавлять данные в таблицу (все, что в коде после else) - то работает, а если с поиском то не работает :(
Подскажите как совместить две функции в одном макросе (Поиск/Замена - и добавление данный в случае если совпадений не найдено).

Comment: Не понятно, что вам необходимо. Кажется, что задачу можно решить в одну строку, но в примере что-то уж больно всего много. Почему в вопросе `onEdit`, а в ответе `doPost`? Что такое "макрос"? В Google Apps Script программы называются "скриптами". Приведите более простой пример. Желательно с Таблицей.

Comment: Есть некий набор данных (json) который попадает ко мне в таблицу при создании ордера(кто, заказал, когда, статус ордера), и данные при обновлении ордера (те же строки)... так вот, прежде чем записать данные - мне необходимо было проверить, есть ли например ордер 728 в таблице, и в случае если таковой имеется - обновлять статус этого ордера в таблице.

В случае если при проверке, такого ордера нет в таблице - просто добавлять данные как новые.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение найдено. Не совсем то, что хотел.
Пришлось сделать два макроса (первый на проверку совпадений, второй на добавление) и запускать их в зависимости, новый ордер, или обновление старого!

---- Обновление старого ордера.

```
function doPost(event) {
  var content = JSON.parse(event.postData.contents);
  var order = content['order'].order_number;

  //colors
  if (content['order'].status == "pending") {
    var clr = '#eeeeee'
    }
  if (content['order'].status == "processing") {
    var clr = '#e5ff00'
    }
  if (content['order'].status == "on-hold") {
    var clr = '#0000ff'
    }
  if (content['order'].status == "completed") {
    var clr = '#00ff00'
    }
  if ((content['order'].status == "cancelled") || (content['order'].status == "refunded") || (content['order'].status == "failed")){
    var clr = '#ff0000'
    }
  //colors

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET_ID"); // ID Вашей таблицы
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var grid = dataRange.getValues();

  grid.forEach(function (row, index) {
    if (row[1] == order) {
      var row = "i" + (index + 1);
      sheet.getRange(row).setValue(content['order'].status)
      sheet.getRange(row).setBackgroundColor(clr);
    }
  });
}
```

---- Добавление нового ордера

```
function doPost(request) {

    var content = JSON.parse(request.postData.contents);
    var row = [];


    row.push(new Date());
    row.push(content['order'].order_number)
    row.push(content['order'].shipping_address.first_name+' '+content['order'].shipping_address.last_name)
    row.push(content['order'].billing_address.email)

    row.push(content['order'].total_line_items_quantity);

    var item = "";
     for (var i=0;content['order'].line_items.length>i;i++){
       item=item+content['order'].line_items[i].quantity+' -'+content['order'].line_items[i].name+',';

    }

    item=item.substring(0,item.length-1);
    row.push(item);
    row.push(content['order'].total)
    row.push(content['order'].payment_details.paid)
    row.push(content['order'].status)
    row.push(content['order'].payment_details.method_title)
    row.push(content['order'].shipping_address.address_1+','+content['order'].shipping_address.city+','+content['order'].shipping_address.country+','+content['order'].billing_address.phone+', ZIP:'+content['order'].billing_address.postcode)

    row.push(content['order'].shipping_methods)

    row.push(content['order'].note)
    row.push(content['order'].view_order_url)

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SPREADSHEET_ID')
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    sheet.appendRow(row);
    result.result = 'ok';

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```